# Managing AlarmManager to repeat an action weekly

Tags: android, alarmmanager, alarm

I've been searching all this morning for a good tutorial in how to use AlarmManager to perform an action weekly. The only thing I've found is this:

[Repeat Alarms on Every Monday in Android usig AlarmManager/BroadcastReceiver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11167025/repeat-alarms-on-every-monday-in-android-usig-alarmmanager-broadcastreceiver)

but it's different from everything else I've read, and I do not fully understand the code.

Could you please help me?

I'm using a form to complete, and with s pushing button, creating an alarm configured by the user. I read all the inputs but then I don't know how to translate it to make an alarm.

Thank you.